# GNU parallel kills command in bash script on HPC

Tags: parallel-processing, hpc

I am running GNU parallel to run a bash script but it seems GNU parallel automatically kills my program and I am not sure why. It run normally when I run the inside script individually.

I wonder why this happen and how to solve it?

Your help is really appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
parallel --progress --joblog ${home}/data/hsc-admmt/Projects/log_a.sh -j 5 :::: a.sh
```

Here is the message at the end of output of GNU parallel

```
/scratch/eu82/bt0689/data/hsc-admmt/Projects/sim_causal_mantel_generate.sh: line 54: 3050285 Killed                  $home/data/hsc-admmt/Tools/mtg2 -plink plink_all${nsamp}${nsnp}_1 -simreal snp.lst1
```

Comment: GNU Parallel should not do that. This leads me to believe something in your environment is causing the problem. Please follow: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#reporting-bugs including https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#bug-dependent-on-environment

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found this possible explanation:

*“Some jobs need a lot of memory, and should only be started when there is enough memory free. Using --memfree GNU parallel can check if there is enough memory free. Additionally, GNU parallel will kill off the youngest job if the memory free falls below 50% of the size. The killed job will put back on the queue and retried later.”*
(from https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

In my case the killed job was not resumed. I’m not sure if this is the reason for your problem but it would explain mine since the error only occurs to me when I parallelize my script for more than 3 jobs.

Comment: You need to add `--retries X` to tell GNU Parallel how many times it should try before giving up.